# Trouble Displaying Weather Data in HTML/JavaScript (displayWeather Error)

Tags: javascript, object

```js
let weather = {
  apiKey: "a5fd20552e868ea7597dd68dec1dd543",
  fetchWeather: function(city) {
    fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
        city +
        "&units=metrics&appid=" +
        this.apiKey
      )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => displayWeather(data));
  },
  //grabs the data from the api and stores it to a variable for disply sing the corresponding key from the file 
  displayWeather: function(data) {
    const name = data;
    const desc = data.weather[0].description;
    const icon = data.weather[0].icon;
    const temp = data.main.temp;
    const speed = data.wind.speed;
    const humidity = data.main.humidity;
    console.log(name, icon, description, temp, speed, humidity);
    document.querySelector(".city").innerHTML = "Weather in " + name;
    document.querySelector(".icon").src = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png";
    document.querySelector.innerText = description;




  },
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/?city,night');
  font-size: 120%;
}

.card {
  background: #000000d0;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420%;
  margin: 1em;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input.search-bar {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 120%;
}

button:hover {
  background: #7c7c7c6b;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/?city,night');
}

.card {
  background: #000000d0;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 420%;
  margin: 1em;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  margin: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 46px;
  width: 46px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input.search-bar {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 24px;
  background: #7c7c7c2b;
  color: white;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 120%;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

h1.temp {
  margin: 0;
}

button:hover {
  background: #7c7c7c6b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Weather App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="weather.css">
  <script src="./weather.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
      <button><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="1.5em" width="1.5em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M909.6 854.5L649.9 594.8C690.2 542.7 712 479 712 412c0-80.2-31.3-155.4-87.9-212.1-56.6-56.7-132-87.9-212.1-87.9s-155.5 31.3-212.1 87.9C143.2 256.5 112 331.8 112 412c0 80.1 31.3 155.5 87.9 212.1C256.5 680.8 331.8 712 412 712c67 0 130.6-21.8 182.7-62l259.7 259.6a8.2 8.2 0 0 0 11.6 0l43.6-43.5a8.2 8.2 0 0 0 0-11.6zM570.4 570.4C528 612.7 471.8 636 412 636s-116-23.3-158.4-65.6C211.3 528 188 471.8 188 412s23.3-116.1 65.6-158.4C296 211.3 352.2 188 412 188s116.1 23.2 158.4 65.6S636 352.2 636 412s-23.3 116.1-65.6 158.4z"></path></svg></button>
    </div>
    <div class="weather">
      <h2 class="city">Denver</h2>
      <h1 class="temp">51° C</h1>
      <img src="" alt="" srcset="" class="icon">
      <div class="description">Cloudy</div>
      <div class="humidity">Humidity: 60%</div>
      <div class="wind">Wind speed: 6.2 km/h</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbjit.png)

I'm currently working on a weather app using HTML and JavaScript, where I retrieve weather data from the OpenWeatherMap API and display it in my HTML document. However, I'm encountering an issue with the displayWeather function, which is responsible for updating the DOM elements with the weather information. and I am getting an error reading the"the data for `weather.description` is '0'".

My code line 15 of the JavaScript file gives me the problem.

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbjit.png)

Answer (score 0):

The flow and logic of the combined HTML document that includes script, CSS, and HTML for fetching and displaying weather information based on a user's input (city name) can be correct weather information.

`Search Input and Button`: A text input field allows the user to type in the name of a city. Next to it, a button is provided for the user to click after entering the city name. The button has an onclick event listener that triggers a JavaScript function to fetch weather data.

`Weather Display Area`: This area is set up to display the weather information once it's fetched. It includes placeholders for the city name, temperature, weather icon, description, humidity, and wind speed

JavaScript parts
`fetchWeather`: This method takes a city name as input, constructs a request URL with the city name and API key, and uses the fetch API to make a GET request to the OpenWeatherMap API. Upon receiving the response, it converts the response to JSON and calls displayWeather with the resulting data.

`displayWeather`: This method takes the weather data JSON as input and extracts relevant pieces of information, such as the city name, weather description, icon, temperature, humidity, and wind speed. It then updates the HTML elements within the weather display area with this data.

#### API test

[image]

#### Whole HTML

Save as `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            background: #222;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random/?city,night');
            font-size: 120%;
        }

        .card {
            background: #000000d0;
            color: white;
            padding: 2em;
            border-radius: 2em;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 420px;
            /* Adjusted to px for consistency */
            margin: 1em;
        }

        .search {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        button {
            border: none;
            margin: 0.5em;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 46px;
            width: 46px;
            background: #7c7c7c2b;
            color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        }

        input.search-bar {
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding: .5em 1em;
            border-radius: 24px;
            background: #7c7c7c2b;
            color: white;
            font-family: inherit;
            font-size: 120%;
            width: calc(100% - 80px);
        }

        button:hover {
            background: #7c7c7c6b;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Enter city name">
            <button onclick="weather.fetchWeather(document.querySelector('.search-bar').value)">
                <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="1.5em"
                    width="1.5em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M909.6 854.5L649.9 594.8C690.2 542.7 712 479 712 412c0-80.2-31.3-155.4-87.9-212.1-56.6-56.7-132-87.9-212.1-87.9s-155.5 31.3-212.1 87.9C143.2 256.5 112 331.8 112 412c0 80.1 31.3 155.5 87.9 212.1C256.5 680.8 331.8 712 412 712c67 0 130.6-21.8 182.7-62l259.7 259.6a8.2 8.2 0 0 0 11.6 0l43.6-43.5a8.2 8.2 0 0 0 0-11.6zM570.4 570.4C528 612.7 471.8 636 412 636s-116-23.3-158.4-65.6C211.3 528 188 471.8 188 412s23.3-116.1 65.6-158.4C296 211.3 352.2 188 412 188s116.1 23.2 158.4 65.6S636 352.2 636 412s-23.3 116.1-65.6 158.4z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="weather">
            <h2 class="city">Weather in <span id="weather-city">...</span></h2>
            <h1 class="temp">...</h1>
            <img src="" alt="" class="icon">
            <div class="description">...</div>
            <div class="humidity">Humidity: ...</div>
            <div class="wind">Wind speed: ...</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let weather = {
            apiKey: "a5fd20552e868ea7597dd68dec1dd543",
            fetchWeather: function (city) {
                fetch("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
                    city +
                    "&units=metric&appid=" + this.apiKey)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => this.displayWeather(data));
            },
            displayWeather: function (data) {
                const { name } = data;
                const { description, icon } = data.weather[0];
                const { temp, humidity } = data.main;
                const { speed } = data.wind;

                document.getElementById("weather-city").innerText = `Weather in ${name}`;
                document.querySelector(".icon").src = `https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${icon}.png`;
                document.querySelector(".description").innerText = `Description: ${description}`; // Ensure description is displayed
                document.querySelector(".temp").innerText = `${temp}° C`;
                document.querySelector(".humidity").innerText = `Humidity: ${humidity}%`;
                document.querySelector(".wind").innerText = `Wind speed: ${speed} km/h`;
            },
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### run HTML server

[Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) in VS code extention.

[image]

Click right /bottom "Go Live" icon.
[image]

##### Access it

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html
```

##### Result

[image]

[image]